# eXist-db query: file:move returning error

Tags: java, xml, xquery, exist-db

I started working with eXide for my job, and i have to say that the documentation is very poor... I couldn't find a solution to this problem:

> err:XPTY0004 checking function parameter 1 in call file:move($position, $destination): XPTY0004: The actual cardinality for parameter 1 does not match the cardinality declared in the function's signature: file:move($original as item(), $destination as item()) xs:boolean. Expected cardinality: exactly one, got 0. [at line 8, column 24, source: xquery version "3.1"; import module namespace file = "http://exist-db.org/xquery/file"; let $log-in := xmldb:login('/db', 'admin', '') for $doc in collection('/db/lime-fao/fao-resolution@lime.com') let $position := document-uri($doc)[contains(., 'main.xml')] let $destination := replace($position, 'main.xml', 'main') return file:move($position,$destination)]

What am i doing wrong? Here's the query:

```
xquery version "3.1";
import module namespace file = "http://exist-db.org/xquery/file"; 

let $log-in := xmldb:login('/db', '*********', '*********')
for $doc in collection('/db/******/******@*****.****')
     let $position := document-uri($doc)[contains(., 'main.xml')]
     let $destination := replace($position, 'main.xml', 'main')
     return file:move($position,$destination)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to check  what value is assigned to the `$position` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following.

**XQuery**

```
...
let $position := base-uri($doc)[ends-with(., 'main.xml')]
```